# docker-compose up error: exec: "air": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, hot-reload

I want to run [air](https://github.com/cosmtrek/air) live-reloading tool on a Docker container.
These are the config and docker files:

Dockerfile:

```
# BASE IMAGE
FROM golang:1.19-alpine AS base

WORKDIR /app

ENV GO111MODULE="on"
ENV GOOS="linux"
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0

RUN apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache \
    build-base \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    tzdata \
    git \
    vips \
    vips-dev \
    && update-ca-certificates

COPY . .

RUN go mod download && go mod verify


# DEVELOPMENT IMAGE
FROM base AS dev

WORKDIR /app

RUN go get -u github.com/cosmtrek/air

EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 2345

ENTRYPOINT ["air", "-c", ".air.conf"]


# BUILDER IMAGE
FROM base AS builder

WORKDIR /app

RUN go build -o myapp


# PRODUCTION IMAGE
FROM alpine:latest as prod

COPY --from=builder /app/myapp /usr/local/bin/myapp

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/myapp"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  myapp-web:
    container_name: myapp-web
    build:
      context: .
      target: dev
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "2345:2345"
    networks:
      - myapp-network

  myapp-db:
    container_name: myapp-db
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - postgres-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - myapp-network

volumes:
  postgres-db:

networks:
  myapp-network:
    name: myapp-network
```

.air.toml:

```
# .air.toml
# Config file for [Air](https://github.com/cosmtrek/air) in TOML format

# Working directory
# . or absolute path, please note that the directories following must be under root.
root = "."
tmp_dir = "tmp"

[build]
# Just plain old shell command. You could use `make` as well.
cmd = "go build -o ./tmp/main ."
# Binary file yields from `cmd`.
bin = "tmp/main"
# Customize binary.
full_bin = "APP_ENV=dev APP_USER=air ./tmp/main"
# Watch these filename extensions.
include_ext = ["go", "tpl", "tmpl", "html"]
# Ignore these filename extensions or directories.
exclude_dir = ["assets", "tmp", "vendor", "frontend/node_modules"]
# Watch these directories if you specified.
include_dir = []
# Exclude files.
exclude_file = []
# It's not necessary to trigger build each time file changes if it's too frequent.
delay = 1000 # ms
# Stop to run old binary when build errors occur.
stop_on_error = true
# This log file places in your tmp_dir.
log = "air_errors.log"

[log]
# Show log time
time = false

[color]
# Customize each part's color. If no color found, use the raw app log.
main = "magenta"
watcher = "cyan"
build = "yellow"
runner = "green"

[misc]
# Delete tmp directory on exit
clean_on_exit = true
```

And with these files when I run `docker-compose up` I get this error message:

```
ERROR: for myapp-web  Cannot start service myapp-web: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "air": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: In your docker-compose file, you map the current directory to /app, thereby hiding everything in the /app directory in the image. Try removing the `volumes:` section under your myapp-web service.

Comment: @HansKilian sorry, it did not solve the issue. same error again...

Comment: If `github.com/cosmtrek/air` is a `main` package you want to install, you need to use `go install`. `go get` only updates the `go.mod` file with the given version.